# What is the most efficient way of finding if unsorted intervals overlap but are not subsets?

Tags: algorithm

I found the solution with time complexity O(n*log(n)) with sorting.
Is there any algorithm that can do this without sorting?

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail - I assume you have N intervals. Do you want to check if any pair of them overlaps or there is a pair that overlaps?

Comment: if any pair of intervals overlap but arent subsets so 1,5 and 2,3 doesn't return 1 but 1,5 and 2,6 does